# Angular does not send httponly cookie with request

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have an Asp Net Core Web API as backend for my Angular web app.
I backend I added CORS

```
app.UseCors(options =>
{
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.AllowAnyMethod();
    options.AllowCredentials();
});
```

Method to append cookie with refresh token to response in backend

```
public void AppendRefreshTokenToCookie(HttpResponse response,RefreshToken token)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(_refreshTokenOptions.Expires),
        HttpOnly = true
    };      
    response.Cookies.Append(_refreshTokenOptions.CookieName,token.Token,cookieOptions);
}
```

Here in angular I send a request to endpoint to receive new jwt token with refresh token (which is in httponly cookie).

```
  RefreshToken():Observable<JwtResponse>{
    return this.http.post<JwtResponse>(this.baseUrl+'/refresh-token',{}).pipe(map(jwtResponse=>{
      this.setJwtToken(jwtResponse);
      return jwtResponse;
    }));
  }
```

Then in backend I check if cookie is in request and generate new jwt token

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RefreshToken()
        {
            var refreshToken = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[_refreshTokenOptions.CookieName];

            if (refreshToken == null)
            {
                var response = ApiResponse.CreateResponse(ApiResponseCodes.RefreshTokenMissing, "Getting new jwt token",
                    "Refresh token is missing");
                return Unauthorized(response);
            }

            User user = await _tokenService.GetUserByRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var response = ApiResponse.CreateResponse(ApiResponseCodes.RefreshTokenMissing, "Getting new jwt token",
                    "Refresh token is missing or expired");
                return Unauthorized(response);
            }
            var jwtToken = await _tokenService.GenerateJwtTokenAsync(user);

            return Ok(jwtToken);
        }
```

But I don't receive any cookies from angular.
When I access the same endpoint with postman, I can generate new jwt token with refresh token in cookie. Even when I use built in swagger ui endpoint is working.
Angular is located at `http://localhost:4200/`, Asp Net Core Web API at `https://localhost:7121/`.
I can see the cookie in browser dev tool.
And when I access generate jwt token endpoint, in response I see headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:4200
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: By default, browsers block cross-origin requests that include cookies, unless the server specifically allows them.
To fix this, you may need to set the withCredentials flag to true in your Angular HTTP requests. Please try with this updated code - https://pastebin.pl/view/43cbe08a

Comment: I just tried adding httpOptions you sent me to both login and refresh token methods and angular still doesn't send cookie with refresh token.  This is screenshot when I'm logging in  in account https://imgur.com/a/mWmZgK2, you can see that I get cookie. And this is screenshot when I'm trying to receive jwt token with refresh token in cookie https://imgur.com/a/KstmM80